# request.GET in Django for Search is not working when entering only one search parameters

Tags: python, django

This is my Search function:
When I use this than I cannot search by only placing for example Keywords only or City only or any other parameters that I have used here.

It comes with no Listing Available.
 But if I remove any search parameters any only work with one parameter like: 
 if I remove all others except #Keywords than my search works out.

```
# search function using request.GET
def search(request):

# for making search option dynamic as per search of user
    queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date')  

    #Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if 'keywords': 
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

    #City
    if 'city' in request.GET:
        city = request.GET['city']
        if 'city': 
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)

    # Bedrooms
    if 'bedrooms' in request.GET:
        bedrooms = request.GET['bedrooms']
        if 'bedrooms':
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bedrooms__lte=bedrooms)

    # Price
    if 'price' in request.GET:
        price = request.GET['price']
        if 'price':             
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(price__lte=price)

    context = {
        'state_choices': state_choices,
        'bedroom_choices': bedroom_choices,
        'price_choices': price_choices,
        'listings': queryset_list,
        'values': request.GET
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

Here is my Template file..... for the Search..

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

<!---Import Humanaize---->
{%load humanize %} {% block title %} | Search Results {%endblock%}
<!---- Start Block Content-->
{%block content%}
<section id="showcase-inner" class="showcase-search text-white py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="{%url 'search' %}">
                    <!-- Form Row 1 -->
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label class="sr-only">Keywords</label>
                            <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword (Pool, Garage, etc)" value="{{values.keywords}}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label class="sr-only">City</label>
                            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="{{values.city}}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label class="sr-only">State</label>
                            <select name="state" class="form-control">
                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">State (All)</option>
                                <!--loop through the key and value pairs-->
                                {%for key, value in state_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}"
                                {% if key == values.state %}
                                selected
                                {%endif%}
                                >
                                {{ value }}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Form Row 2 -->
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <label class="sr-only">Bedrooms</label>
                            <select name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Bedrooms (Any)</option>
                                <!--loop through the key and value pairs-->
                                {%for key, value in bedroom_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}"
                                    {% if key == values.bedrooms %}
                                     selected
                                    {%endif%}
                                >{{ value }}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <select name="price" class="form-control">
                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Max Price (All)</option>
                                <!--loop through the key and value pairs-->
                                {%for key, value in price_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}"
                                    {% if key == values.price %}
                                    selected
                                    {%endif%}
                                >
                                {{ value }}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Submit form</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<section id="bc" class="mt-3">
    <div class="container">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="{%url 'index'%}">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="{%url 'listings' %}">Browse Listings</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Search Results</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Listings -->
<section id="listings" class="py-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            {%if listings %} {% for listing in listings %}
            <!-- Listing 1 -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                <div class="card listing-preview">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}" alt="">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="badge badge-secondary text-white">${{listing.price | intcomma}}</span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                            <h4 class="text-primary">{{listing.title}}</h4>
                            <p>
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker text-secondary"></i> {{listing.city}} {{listing.state}}, {{listing.zipcode}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Sqft: {{listing.sqft}}</div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fas fa-car"></i> Garage: {{listing.garage}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Bedrooms: {{listing.bedrooms}}</div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fas fa-bath"></i> Bathrooms: {{listing.bathrooms}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i> {{listing.realtor}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row text-secondary pb-2">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{listing.list_date | timesince}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
            <!----if above is not true------>
            {%else%}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>
                    No Listings Available
                </p>
            </div>

            <!------end of the if statement ------>
            {%endif%}

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Can you change request.GET['keyword'] sections with request.GET.get('keyword') and try again?

Comment: Out of general curiosity, does this not fetch the entire table’s worth of rows and **then** filter the in-RAM result set?  Is this customary, at least outside of small tables?  I don’t use the ORM much except through the admin so might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see there is a small error in your view. A statement like

```
if 'keywords' in request.GET:
```

will not check whether 'keywords' is empty. I will always return True as long as there is a field called 'keywords' in your form.

Then your checks like

```
if 'keywords':
```

will always return `True` as you are not checking the variable but a string. What you probably mean is

```
if keywords:
```

to check if keywords contains something.

So what is currently happening is that - as all your checks are returning `True` - your are filtering your queryset using a lot of empty strings, and this will return an empty queryset.

So remove the `''` from your checks like `if 'keywords':` and the other similar `if` statements.

If you want you can also remove the `if 'keywords' in request.GET:` and similar as they always return `True`.